# Parse PHP SDK stay logged in after browser restart

Tags: php, session, parse-platform, authentication

I know parse has this functionality through the session tokens but the guide doesn't show you how to use them and I need some help.

Currently I am checking if the user is logged in or not by:

```
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

if($currentUser == null){
    // not logged in
}
else{
   // logged in
}
```

But whenever I restart the browser, the user is logged out because the _SESSION data is deleted. How can I check for a valid parse session token using PHP to use persistent login?